# How to add attributes in combination of object detection using YOLO?

Tags: computer-vision, attributes, object-detection, yolov5, yolov4

I'm new to computer vision and I'm wondering how to deal with the following problem.

I'm using YOLO for real time objet detection task. However I'm dealing with a dataset that gives me also few attributes such has weather, temperature etc...

(I'm obviously able to acces to those informations in real time, to use them in real life).

My data has some big differences depending of the weather, temperature etc... that's why it's useful to have access to those informations.

So is there any way to learn on both image dataset associated to a context ? I'm looking for something that is YOLO compatible.

If a such thing isn't compatible/doesn't exists, I guess I'll just do different versions of the trained YOLO on specifics datasets associated to different context. Each specific version will be actived only for specific weather and temperature.

Thank you in advance for any kind of help/informations.

Comment: you would have to modify the network... -- please ask on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build you custom model that combines visual features with tabular data. This could look something like:

```py
vis_feats = nn.Linear(512, 1)  # visual features
tab_feats = nn.Linear(4, 1)    # tab features
x = torch.cat((x, tab), dim=1) # x goes into your prediction layer
```